# Como eu faço para habilitar o PostGresql no Cpanel?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, cpanel, pgadmin, whm

Boa tarde. Gostaria de saber como faço para ativar o Postgres no menu do Cpanel da parte de banco de dados, preciso criar um banco em Pg. Já fiz a instalação no WHM e habilitei a configuração, entretanto ainda não está aparecendo a opção para que eu crie o banco via Cpanel. Alguém tem um tutorial para isso? eu já segui esses e nenhum deles deu jeito.

http://wiki.integrator.com.br/index.php?title=Instalando_e_configurando_o_PostgreSQL_9_no_cPanel/WHM

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/Install+or+Update+PostgreSQL+on+Your+cPanel+Server

Answer (score 0):

Boa Tarde,

Instalei sem problemas utilizando os passos abaixo.

1. Execute o comando / usr / local / cpanel / scripts / installpostgres para instalar ou atualizar o PostgreSQL.
2. Acesse a interface ConfigurePostgreSQL do WHM (WHM >> Home >> Serviços SQL >> Configure o PostgreSQL).
3. Clique em Instalar Configuração se o PostgreSQL não existir no seu servidor.

Quais dúvidas estou a disposição.

Att,
Tiago Ceridorio

Comment: Obrigado por responder, Tiago. Esse problema eu resolvi ligando para o suporte do host. :)